# objective-c filling a view with a pattern

Tags: objective-c, view, design-patterns

I have a view which I created in IB. I have the graphic file in my resource folder. I'm trying to fill the view with the graphic as a repeating (x and y) graphic (it'll make a grid).

Here's my code:

```
-(void) awakeFromNib { 

//set background patterns using, loading it through NSImage
[[NSColor colorWithPatternImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"ts_bg_pattern.png"]] set];

NSRect splashFrame = [splashScreen frame];

//fill view with background pattern
[NSBezierPath fillRect:[splashScreen bounds]];

sleep(5);

if (splashFrame.origin.x == 0) { 
    [[splashScreen animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect(-1123.0, 0.0, 212.0, 612.0)];
}
}
```

This compiles but does nothing. I'm pretty sure my error is with the NSBezierPath. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work in `awakeFromNib`. You should implement `drawRect:` in your view subclass, and put the drawing code there. Also you should use `NSRectFill()` to fill a rectangle.